# My java code has no errors but stops at nextInt

Tags: java, selenium, automation

I'm writing a Java code that would run a simple automation scenario in Chrome or Firefox - depending on the user's input. There are no underlined errors, but the program is stuck at the nextInt line (saw it in the Debugger), and there is no output. Could anyone help?
Thanks!

```
package com.selenium;

import java.util.Scanner;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        // environment variable
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Automation\\libs\\Drivers\\chromedriver.exe");
        //WebDriver chromeDriver = new ChromeDriver();
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Automation\\libs\\Drivers\\geckodriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = null;

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int option = scanner.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Please enter 1 for Chrome or 2 for Firefox " + option);
        if (option == 1)
        {
            WebDriver driver1= new FirefoxDriver();
        }
        else if 
        (option == 2)
        {
            WebDriver driver2 = new ChromeDriver();
        }
        else 
            System.out.println("Please enter a correct number " + option);

        String baseURL = "https://login.salesforce.com/?locale=eu";

        driver.get(baseURL);

        WebElement userName = driver.findElement(By.id("username"));
        userName.sendKeys("Yan");

        WebElement password = driver.findElement(By.id("password"));
        password.sendKeys("123456");

        WebElement rememberCheckbox = driver.findElement(By.id("rememberUn"));
        rememberCheckbox.click();

        WebElement bLogin = driver.findElement(By.id("Login"));
        bLogin.click();

        }

    }
```

Comment: Have you tried unsticking it by giving it some input?

Comment: Did you input something?

Answer (score 2):

Put your `System.out` before the `scanner.nextInt()`

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Please enter 1 for Chrome or 2 for Firefox " + option);
int option = scanner.nextInt();
```

Then type 1 or 2 on the keyboard when it asks you to enter a number.